# Check if column exists on a table

Tags: peewee

For context: I am writing a script to do DB migrations.

Would like to check a Model against the actual table to see if all the fields exists.

Or would like to run a check on whether a specific column (field) exists on the table.

I can see that http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.table_exists exists so I'm looking for the corollary for a Field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `database.get_columns('table_name')` and it will return the columns on the table.